# Android Overlaying a text on top of an ImageButton

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I've got an Image button and want to place on top of it a descriptive text. Also need the ImageButton to be 1/3 of the parent's width so can't use a ConstraintLayout nor a LinearLayout. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your `ImageView` and `TextView` in a `RelativeLayout` as:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and set `android:weightSum=3` in the parent layout. Once you have the desired layout, make the `RelativeLayout` clickable instead of using an `ImageButton`.

Comment: This suggestion worked, I placed it all within a LinearLayout so I could use weightSum.